# ffmpeg: h263 codec not supported in mp4 container

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to encode a file using ffmpeg codec h263 into an mp4 container. I get the following error whenever I try to do so:
[mp4 @ 01FC05E0] track 0: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container

Is there any work-around for this? I am using a static build of ffmpeg (on windows)

Could anyone please help

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your copy of ffmpeg doesn't support putting video encoded as h263 into an mp4 file.

This is probably because mp4 is meant for h26**4** encoded video.